# Multiprocessing gremlinpython queries

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, janusgraph, gremlinpython

### Goal:

Accelerate the random walk generation by using multiple processes.

1. Get the list of vertices ids from which I want random walks to be generated in an input queue
2. Start as much processes as possible with the correct parameters
3. Make them put the random walks into an output queue
4. Wait for completion
5. Read the output queue

### What I am doing:

```py
# Libraries imports
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Process, Queue
import queue

import configparser
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import AnonymousTraversalSource, traversal
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __

# Function the processes are supposed to execute
def job(proc_id:int, siq:Queue, rwq:Queue, g:AnonymousTraversalSource, length:int):
    while True:
        try:
            # Get next element in ids queue
            start_id = siq.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            # If the ids queue is empty, then terminate
            break
        else:
            # Do a random walk of length <length> from the vertex with id <start_id>
            random_walk = g.V(start_id).repeat(
                __.local(__.both().sample(1))
            ).times(length).path().next()
            print(f"{proc_id}: rw obtained")
            # Transform the list of vertices into a comma-separated string of ids
            rwq.put(",".join(
                [str(v.id) for v in random_walk]
            ))
            print(f"{proc_id}: rw handled")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the parameters from the <config.ini> configuration file
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    jg_uri = config["JANUSGRAPH"]["URI"]
    file_random_walks = config["FILES"]["RANDOM_WALKS"]
    walks_nb_per_node = int(config["WALKS"]["NB_PER_NODE"])
    walks_length = int(config["WALKS"]["LENGTH"])

    # Connect to Janus Graph
    connection = DriverRemoteConnection(jg_uri, "g")
    g_main = traversal().withRemote(connection)

    # Instantiate the queues and populate the ids one
    start_ids_queue = Queue()
    random_walks_queue = Queue()
    for vertex in g_main.V().has("vertex_label", "<label>").fold().next():
        start_ids_queue.put(vertex.id)

    # Create and start the processes
    nb_processes = cpu_count()
    processes = []
    for i in range(nb_processes):
        p = Process(target=job, args=(
            i,
            start_ids_queue,
            random_walks_queue,
            g_main,
            walks_length
        ))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # Once the processes are terminated, read the random walks queue
    random_walks = []
    while not random_walks_queue.empty():
        random_walks.append(random_walks_queue.get())

    # Do something with the random walks
    ...
```

### Issue:

Once the processes are started, nothing seems to happen. I never get the `X: rw obtained`/`X: rw handled` messages. With a bit more logging, I can see that the queries have been sent yet isn't finishing.
In the logs, when performing the first `g_main.V().has("vertex_label", "<label>").fold().next()` in the main process (when I populate the ids queue), I have the following message:

```
DEBUG:gremlinpython:submit with bytecode '[['V'], ['has', 'vertex_label', 'movie'], ['fold']]'
DEBUG:gremlinpython:message '[['V'], ['has', 'vertex_label', '<label>'], ['fold']]'
DEBUG:gremlinpython:processor='traversal', op='bytecode', args='{'gremlin': [['V'], ['has', 'vertex_label', '<label>'], ['fold']], 'aliases': {'g': 'g'}}'
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
```

When the other processes send their queries, I have similar logs:

```
DEBUG:gremlinpython:submit with bytecode '[['V', 16456], ['repeat', [['local', [['both'], ['sample', 1]]]]], ['times', 10], ['path']]'
DEBUG:gremlinpython:message '[['V', 16456], ['repeat', [['local', [['both'], ['sample', 1]]]]], ['times', 10], ['path']]'
DEBUG:gremlinpython:processor='traversal', op='bytecode', args='{'gremlin': [['V', 16456], ['repeat', [['local', [['both'], ['sample', 1]]]]], ['times', 10], ['path']], 'aliases': {'g': 'g'}}'
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
```

The issue seems not to reside in the query sent, but instead in the indefinite wait that ensues.
If you know of an issue with `gremlinpython` and `multiprocessing`, if there is a problem in my multi-processing code, or if you have any explanation that I may have overlooked, please explain to me! Thanks a lot to everyone reading this!

### Solutions:

The first partial solution that I found is to use multi-threading instead of multiprocessing:

```py
import configparser
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import AnonymousTraversalSource, traversal
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __

import threading

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, g, length):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.thread_count = 0
        self.gtraversal = g
        self.walk_length = length
        self.nb_walks = nb_walks
    def run(self):
        while True:
            start_ids_list_lock.acquire()
            try:
                start_id = start_ids_list.pop(0)
                start_ids_list_lock.release()
            except IndexError:
                start_ids_list_lock.release()
                break
            else:
                self.thread_count += 1
                random_walk = job(
                    vertex_id=start_id,
                    g=self.gtraversal,
                    length=self.walk_length,
                    nb_walks=self.nb_walks
                )
                random_walks_list_lock.acquire()
                random_walks_list.append(random_walk)
                random_walks_list_lock.release()
                logging.info(f"Thread {self.thread_id}: {self.thread_count} done")

def job(vertex_id:int, g:AnonymousTraversalSource, length:int) -> str:
    random_walk = g.V(vertex_id).repeat(
        __.local(__.both().sample(1))
    ).times(length).path().next()
    return ",".join(random_walk)

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
jg_uri = config["JANUSGRAPH"]["URI"]
file_random_walks = config["FILES"]["RANDOM_WALKS"]
walks_length = int(config["WALKS"]["LENGTH"])

connection = DriverRemoteConnection(jg_uri, "g")
g_main = traversal().withRemote(connection)

threads = []
start_ids_list = []
random_walks_list = []
random_walks_list_lock = threading.Lock()
start_ids_list_lock = threading.Lock()

start_ids_list = [vertex.id for vertex in g_main.V().has("vertex_label", "<label>").fold().next()]
nb_vertices = len(start_ids_list)

nb_threads = 6
for i in range(nb_threads):
    thread = myThread(
        thread_id=i,
        g=g_main,
        length=walks_length
    )
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
for t in threads:
    t.join()

# Do something with the random walks
...
```

This solution is effectively working and improves the execution time of the program. This isn't a full answer though, as it doesn't explain why the multiprocessing is not performing as I expected.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but appears you're generating processes based on the number of CPUs but doesn't appear that you're doing anything with the connection pool_size.  Default pool_size for gremlinpython is 8, but you should probably set your pool_size to be equal to the number of processes you're creating. At the same time, you may also want to set max_workers to a number higher than the pool_size (in the past, Python defaulted to cpus*5 for this setting).

Comment: Do you think I should do it with the multi-threading script too? I am not too sure about what these do, and I can't find any precise documentation... (Is it really lacking or have I missed some?).  
As you suspected, it doesn't solve the issue though (but doing things the better way is nice).