# Default handling of simultaneous Gremlin queries

Tags: python, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython

### Goal

I want to understand the way JanusGraph is handling simultaneous gremlin queries. Is it sequential or parallel? How is it decided?
The underlying interest is that I need to do a lot of computations and graph walks. I have everything in local on my machine and, while I have parallelized the gremlinpython script, there seems to be a bottleneck somewhere.

### Configuration

- JanusGraph 0.6.1 full
- Local graph (default `conf/remote.yaml` file used)

### What I am doing

Each thread is created with a couple of attributes, in particular, they all get an `AnonymousTraversalSource`. They will then pop an element from the start vertices list, execute the following code, and repeat until the list is empty.

```py
def job(vertex_id:int, g:AnonymousTraversalSource, length:int, nb_walks:int) -> str:
    random_walks = []
    for _ in range(nb_walks):
        random_walk = g.V(vertex_id).repeat(
            __.local(__.both().sample(1))
        ).times(length).path().next()
        random_walks.append(",".join([str(v.id) for v in random_walk]))
    return "\n".join(random_walks)
```

The traversals are defined as such:

```py
connection = DriverRemoteConnection(<URL>, "g")
g = traversal().with_remote(connection)
```

The threads are defined as follow:

```py
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, g, length, nb_walks):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.thread_count = 0
        self.gtraversal = g
        self.walk_length = length
        self.nb_walks = nb_walks
    def run(self):
        while True:
            start_ids_list_lock.acquire()
            try:
                start_id = start_ids_list.pop(0)
                start_ids_list_lock.release()
            except IndexError:
                start_ids_list_lock.release()
                break
            else:
                self.thread_count += 1
                random_walk = job(
                    vertex_id=start_id,
                    g=self.gtraversal,
                    length=self.walk_length,
                    nb_walks=self.nb_walks
                )
                random_walks_list_lock.acquire()
                random_walks_list.append(random_walk)
                random_walks_list_lock.release()
```

### What I tried

I tried:

- Giving the same `AnonymousTraversalSource` object
- Giving different `AnonymousTraversalSource` objects instantiated with the same `DriverRemoteConnection` object
- Giving different `AnonymousTraversalSource` objects built with different `DriverRemoteConnection` objects

None of these options were noticeably faster the others, all of them were doing around 500 random walks in 20-25secs

### Issue

Is there maybe a problem in the way I built my `DriverRemoteConnection` or `AnonymousTraversalSource` objects?
Is there a way to improve performances? Have I reached the limits of what is possible this way?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Python threads are not the same as the preemptive multitasking style ones used by operating systems, or languages like Java.

Python uses cooperative multitasking when you use the built in threads. This means that they may yield during IO waits but in general they will never yield otherwise and just run one after the other.

You may want to consider using the multiprocessing library instead.

In either case, sharing the `g` object between threads is the correct approach to use.

If you can share more of the code that you are using, in particular how you created and deployed the threads, I will update this answer as appropriate.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this aspect of Python threads to be honest! I already tried to use multiprocessing but I wasn't able to get it to work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816825/multiprocessing-gremlinpython-queries). I will also update my post with a little bit more details.